# Confused about remote debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a console app that I am trying to debug using remote debugger.

Clearly it seems you need to first run the application on the remote server, then attach to process.

My question is, whats the preferred method to catch the code at the start of execution, so it won't run away by the time you've managed to hookup the debugger.

Is there an industry standard best practice way to hook in and pause execution at a certain point till the debugger is attached?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to launch the remote app from Visual Studio.

1. Go to the **Debug** tab in project properties window.
2. Select **Start external program** and specify the exe path. (e.g. C:\MyTestApp\MyTestApp.exe)
3. Check **Use remote machine** and enter the name of the remote machine.

Detailed explanation [here](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/11/16/remote-debugging-from-visual-studio-2010/).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a way to attach to a process in remote machine before the process starts. But , have you considered using [Intellitrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915%28VS.100%29.aspx) to see the events and state of your program?

There is a way to [attach a debugger to a Application automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx) when the application launches. But I am not sure if it would work on remote debugging.

Similarly the [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) would launch a process and start a Debugger attached to it. Again it doesn't support Remote launching and debugging.